# Protecting QGIS Plugin source code

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

We are developing a QGIS Plugin.

Considering we can only use Python, is there any way to protect our intellectual property?

Comment: I don't understand why there is such a huge gap between downvotes for the question upvotes for the answer. Yes, the question does not include some conceptions, outlook, and thinkings. However, I consider it as a valid question even it contradicts the main idea of FOSS.

Comment: This question is not about GIS. It is pure coincidence that the author is developing for QGIS, it could be asked the same way for a huge pile of other environments. Better asked in https://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sharing your "intellectual property" under licence GPLv2 is maybe a loss of profits from your point of view, but without Open Source, QGIS wouldn't be as it is, 0$ ever licence. And its documentation ? And all tutorials or tools for building plugins ? There is maybe some possibilities for monetize your work, looks at SLYR, a QGIS plugin developed by Nyall Dawson : https://north-road.com/slyr/.

Comment: @J.Monticolo also consider the fact that plenty of open source software makers are quite successful financially. GPLv2 doesn't stop you from charging money for support or implementation of custom new features.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

QGIS is licensed under the GPLv2, this same license applies to QGIS plugins.

QGIS has written a [blog post that clarifies on the licensing as well as on the commercial aspects of this](https://blog.qgis.org/2016/05/29/licensing-requirements-for-qgis-plugins/).

With respect to your question, here is the most relevant part quoted. However, I would suggest to read the complete blog post to also be aware that this is not meant to undermine any commercial intentions.

> Under the terms of this license, it is a requirement that all plugins distributed via http://plugins.qgis.org (or through other repositories that may be self-hosted) should comply with the GPL version 2 or greater license. In particular all code included in any plugin should be made clearly and easily available in source form. It has come to our attention that some plugin authors are distributing plugins that do not comply with this condition.

In summary, while the question probably was looking for a technical solution, the question that needs to be asked first is a legal one.
The question about "protection of your IP" needs to be considered in the context of "your work being based on work that is published under the GPL", in this case QGIS. Within these limits you are **required** to give access to the source code to anyone you give the plugin to.
On the other hand, you are **not required** to give the plugin to anyone. And you are also **not required** to give the plugin to anyone free of cost.

P.S. I am not a lawyer

Comment: I think QGIS are actually wrong to claim that plugins must comply with GPLv2. Python plugins don't even link to any static libraries or headers, since Python is a dynamic language. So there's no way to consider a plugin by itself to be a derived work just because it's a plugin for a GPLv2 application.

Comment: But you do pull in GPL modules that your plugin will not work with out.

Comment: @TrayMan There's a plausible-sounding (but untested AFAIK) legal argument that importing a Python module is equivalent to linking for the GPL's definition of derivative works, because the imported module and the importing module communicate by function calls and exchanging complex data structures. That doesn't necessarily mean QGIS are right, I'm just saying it's not clear the no-linking argument you made would hold up in court. See e.g. https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/2139.

Comment: More importantly, it's not clear that argument will *keep you from being sued*. Who cares if you win; spending months in court to get there would be awful.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way to protect your 'intellectual property' would be not to publish it. But be aware that you would not be able to write any QGIS plugin without using the 'intellectual property' of a big community of contributors to QGIS.

Comment: The question was about legal aspects, but your answer is about community ethics.

Comment: A large community of contributors brought us most programming languages and proprietary software still exists.

Answer (score 6):

Others have discussed the licensing/legal requirements of releasing QGIS plug-in source code. To the extent your concern is about others not mucking/damaging/repackaging and "profiting from" your work, you should consider QGIS' **free-and-open-source (FOSS) approach a feature, not a bug**. By writing transparent source code that others can read and modify, your plug-in can be improved and due to everyone doing so, the ecosystem overall continues to expand over time. This is the secret weapon by which FOSS can "compete" with proprietary commercial software.

To the extent you nevertheless have important IP that needs to be segregated (for instance proprietary algorithms, or private data, or merely data to which you have added significant value by processing whose cost you need to amortize), you could perhaps explore a hybrid architecture. For instance, your open-source plug-in could be the **bridge to a proprietary separate tool** you distribute, or **obtain data from an online service you would operate** (users would authenticate).

In addition to the SLYR plug-in mentioned by Matthias, examples include https://www.maptiler.com/qgis-plugin/ and https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SentinelHub/. Each of these are plug-ins with source code available, but with considerable IP retained by separating out the value-added processed data feed (incidentally, in both cases built upon more freely licensed underlying base data.)

Finally, if you're just concerned that your work spreads too broadly/rapidly, you need not disseminate your plug-in through the public QGIS plug-in repository. You can distribute it manually to target users, or even set up a **private "unlisted" repository** of your own.

Answer (score -2):

You can obfuscate your code to make it harder to reverse engineer and to hide the original source code. [PyArmor](https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/) is appears to be a tool for obfuscating Python code.

Comment: The GPLv3 defines source code as "the preferred form of the work for making modifications to it", so obfuscated Python code wouldn't be source code under that definition. I don't think that definition exists in the GPLv2, but still, the lawyers would probably argue that distributing obfuscated code doesn't count.

Comment: @DavidZ The GPLv2 says that too.

Comment: Ah right, thanks, somehow I missed seeing it on my earlier reading. So yeah, obfuscated Python code is not source code in the relevant sense.

Comment: I wonder how this can be the accepted answer, since it recommends a clear license violation (with possible unpleasant consequences)

Comment: (ironic) I propose to write all messages on StackExchange sites in abbreviation and rot13 ...